How to convert Oracle/Java datetime in long type
I have timestamps from Oracle stored in a CSV file as data type long. This timestamp is generated using the Java function getTime(), see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html
Timestamp looks like this, for example: 1723207241234. In the Oracle documentation I found that it is milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
So, I need to parse timestamp generated using Java function in Oracle (get date and time from timestamp) and store these values ​​in SAS tables. Is there any way to do this?

The overarching approach is Instant.ofEpochMilli(1723207241234L); It would then depend on what you mean by 'date' and 'time' (e.g. date and time where, and how do you want to use them?) Local might be ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1723207241234L), ZoneId.systemDefault());

SAS date-times are seconds since January 1, 1960.  So perhaps something like want=have/1000+('01Jan1970:00:00:00'dt - '01Jan1960:00:00:00'dt );.

I am a bit confused - How is this question related to Java? And how to SAS? What exactly do you need?

You supplied a value. And the value you supplied is a reasonably recent date, not one to which you needed to add ten years...

What @g00se said. ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1723207241234L), ZoneId.systemDefault()) gives 2024-08-09T14:40:41.234+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen] in my time zone. Does that sound reasonable?

What did your search bring up? Please always search before asking a question here. In this case what you find should already bring you far. The greatest challenge may be steering clear of old web pages using Date, Calendar and/or -- ouch! -- SimpleDateFormat, since those classes are full of trouble and long outdated.

CSV files do not have data types.  Do you mean the timestamp is stored in the CSV files as streams of digits like the examples you showed?

This timestamp is generated using the Java function getTime() Well, of course that's not the earliest point in the chain of events, there would have to be a ResultSet first to call that method. So you might consider calling instead rs.getObject(columnIndex, java.time.Instant.class)

So, I need to parse timestamp generated using Java function in Oracle (get date and time from timestamp) And of course, Instant is a date and time (in UTC)

SAS stores its datetimes since seconds from Jan 1st, 1960 00:00:00 GMT. To convert this to a SAS datetime, you must add 10 years to the Unix datetime value in seconds. '01JAN1970:00:00'dt in SAS converts to 10 years in seconds.
data want;
    time = 1723207241234/1000 + '01JAN1970:00:00'dt;
    format time datetime20.;
run;

time
09AUG2024:12:40:41

